# Hadoop FileSystem mkdirs() creates directory with 755 permission when passed 777

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

fileSystem object used in snippet below has been obtained via `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(Configuration conf)`.

FsPermission object passed below has been obtained via `FsPermission.getDefault()` which is 777.

```
public int mkdirs(Path f, FsPermission permission) {
    try {
      return fileSystem.mkdirs(f, permission) ? 0 : 1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOG.error("Failed to execute 'mkdirs': " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return 1;
}
```

However resulting directory created has 755 permission even when passed 777.

What could be amiss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [process `umask`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) is almost certainly set to `022` and masking the bits.

[Per the Wikipedia entry on `umask`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask):

> In computing, umask is a command that determines the settings of a
>   mask that controls how file permissions are set for newly created
>   files. It also may refer to a function that sets the mask, or it may
>   refer to the mask itself, which is formally known as the file mode
>   creation mask. The mask is a grouping of bits, each of which restricts
>   how its corresponding permission is set for newly created files. The
>   bits in the mask may be changed by invoking the umask command.
>
> In UNIX, each file has a set of attributes which control who can read,
>   write or execute it. When a program creates a file, UNIX requires that
>   the file permissions be set to an initial setting. The mask restricts
>   permission settings. If the mask has a bit set to "1", it means the
>   corresponding initial file permission will be disabled. A bit set to
>   "0" in the mask means that the corresponding permission will be
>   determined by the program and the system. In other words, the mask
>   acts as a last-stage filter that strips away permissions as a file is
>   created; each bit that is set to a "1" strips away its corresponding
>   permission. Permissions may be changed later by users and programs
>   using chmod.
>
> Each program (technically called a process) has its own mask, and is
>   able to change its settings using a function call. ...

With `umask` set to `022` (octal), creating something with requested permissions of `0777` will result in final permissions of `0755`.

Comment: A small clarification: when writing a file to HDFS, the client process umask at the OS layer is not a factor.  Instead, the configuration property `fs.permissions.umask-mode` controls the umask.  It behaves similarly to the traditional POSIX `umask`, and its default value is set to `022`, so this answer is otherwise correct.  Thanks!